# How to call a person who gets transcendental very easily and continuously?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to describe a person who gets metaphisically transcendental very easily.

That is, getting in a very deep mood quite fast, even though the situation is not that serious, like:

> A: I think we should have dinner now.
>
> B: Yes, life is too short to wait.
>
> A: Yes, B, but don't be that X, no need to be that transcendental :)

Is there a word for this? I was thinking in "transcendental" but I wonder if some other adjective may fit better.

Comment: Don't get it too trascendentally ;D

Comment: If they really looked like they were thinking about it too deeply, I'd be more inclined to say something like, "Ok, don't blow a gasket- it's just dinner."

Comment: ‘Life is too sort to wait’ verges on an aphorism, so perhaps *aphorismic*?

Comment: how about "A: Yes B, but don't be so serious, no need to be that philosophical."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an excerpt from Shakespeare's *As You Like It*.

> DUKE SENIOR
>      Come, shall we go and kill us venison?
>      And yet it irks me the poor dappled fools,
>      Being native burghers of this desert city,
>      Should in their own confines with forked heads
>      Have their round haunches gored.
>
> FIRST LORD
>      Indeed, my lord,
>      The melancholy Jaques grieves at that,
>      And, in that kind, swears you do more usurp
>      Than doth your brother that hath banish'd you.
>      Today my Lord of Amiens and myself
>      Did steal behind him as he lay along
>      Under an oak whose antique root peeps out
>      Upon the brook that brawls along this wood:
>      To the which place a poor sequest'red stag,
>      That from the hunter's aim had ta'en a hurt,
>      Did come to languish, and indeed, my lord,
>      The wretched animal heaved forth such groans
>      That their discharge did stretch his leathern coat
>      Almost to bursting, and the big round tears
>      Coursed one another down his innocent nose
>      In piteous chase; and thus the hairy fool,
>      Much marked of the melancholy Jaques,
>      Stood on the extremest verge of the swift brook,
>      Augmenting it with tears.
>
> DUKE SENIOR
>      But what said Jaques?
>      Did he not moralize this spectacle?
>
> FIRST LORD
>      O, yes, into a thousand similes.
>      First, for his weeping into the needless stream;
>      'Poor deer,' quoth he, 'thou makest a testament
>      As worldlings do, giving thy sum of more
>      To that which had too much:' then, being there alone,
>      Left and abandon'd of his velvet friends,
>      ''Tis right:' quoth he; 'thus misery doth part
>      The flux of company.' Anon a careless herd,
>      Full of the pasture, jumps along by him
>      And never stays to greet him; 'Ay' quoth Jaques,
>      'Sweep on, you fat and greasy citizens;
>      'Tis just the fashion: wherefore do you look
>      Upon that poor and broken bankrupt there?'
>      Thus most invectively he pierceth through
>      The body of the country, city, court,
>      Yea, and of this our life, swearing that we
>      Are mere usurpers, tyrants and what's worse,
>      To fright the animals and to kill them up
>      In their assign'd and native dwelling-place.

Jaques(the person being referred to in the conversation between Duke Senior and the First Lord) is the kind of person that gets "in a very deep mood quite fast, even though the situation is not that serious". People call him ***melancholic*** for this reason.

**Melancholic**:

> a :  depression of spirits, dejection
>
> b :  a pensive mood

If the situation is not very serious but the person takes it seriously, you can simply call him ***pensive***.

**Pensive**:

> quietly sad or thoughtful

Source: [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/)

Comment: I wouldn't imagine "melancholic" as the word, since it has a sad connotation that is not the one I am looking for. However, "pensive" looks like a good one. Many thanks for it and for the references, beautiful answer!

Comment: Thank you. Yes, melancholic has a sad connotation. I was a little doubtful about it but it seemed to be the perfect word. You can try using 'ruminant'. A ruminant is a person who ruminates or thinks a lot(seriously). It's not the exact word, but you can try it. 'Metaphysically transcendental' is awesome, but I'm afraid it's too long to be used to describe someone.